# error System.AccessViolationException VS2010

Tags: access-violation

I have a **System.AccessViolationException** and i don't know how it's possible. I narrowed down the arrays to a simple :

```
analyzedReal[0][0][0] <- works
analyzedReal[1][0][0] <- fails.
```

Here is my  code:

```
--in temp.h --
double*** analyzedReal;
double*** analyzedImag;

--in temp.cpp :--
int nbAnalyses = 215;
analyzedReal = new double**[nbAnalyses];
analyzedImag = new double**[nbAnalyses];

for (int i = 0; i < nbAnalyses; i++)
{
  analyzedReal[i] = new double*[2048];
  analyzedImag[i] = new double*[2048];

 for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++)
  {
    analyzedReal[i][j] = new double[10];
    analyzedImag[i][j] = new double[10];
  } 
}
```

It happens only on the array **analyzedReal** not on **analyzedImag** oddly enough

I thought it was some kind of memory leakage so I restarted but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbAnalyses; i++)
{
  analyzedReal[i] = new double*[2048];
  analyzedImag[i] = new double*[2048];
 
 for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++)
  {
    analyzedReal[i][j] = new double[10];
    analyzedImag[i][j] = new double[10];
  } 
}
```

Write this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbAnalyses; i++)
{
  analyzedReal[i] = new double*[2048];
  analyzedImag[i] = new double*[2048];
}
for (int i = 0; i < nbAnalyses; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++)
  {
    analyzedReal[i][j] = new double[10];
    analyzedImag[i][j] = new double[10];
  } 
}
```